# javascript : Best way to create class

Tags: javascript, class

I've been creating javascript class objects with the structure below. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
function MyClass(config)
{
    this.init(config);
}

MyClass.prototype = 
{
    that:this,
    config:null,

    init:function(config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        this.blah();
    },

    blah:function()
    {
        if(this.config.blah)
        {
            console.log(this.config.blah)
        }
    }
}

new MyClass({blah:"helloWorld"});
```

Comment: "Better" is always debatable. I do think it's work that you're putting `that` and `config` directly on to the prototype rather than just the instances themselves. You could make a case for using the [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) in browsers that support it. Really, it's just what works best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to have all content of a class in an enclosure.

`that` won't have `MyClass` instance as set in your example.

```
var MyClass = (function () {

    var MyClass = function (config) {

        // Optional check whether the class was accessed using new
        if (!(this instanceof MyClass))
            throw new Error('You must create the instance using the keyword new');

        // Don't add it to the prototype as it is unique to the instance
        this.config = config;

        this.blah();
    };

    MyClass.prototype = {

        blah: function () {

            if (this.config.blah)
                console.log(this.config.blah);
        }
    };

    return MyClass;

})();

// That has the instance now
var that = new MyClass ({
    blah: 'helloWorld'
});
```

If you can use ES6 than you could try:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor (config) {

        // Don't add it to the prototype as it is unique to the instance
        this.config = config;

        this.blah();
    }

    get config () {
        return this._config;
    }

    set config (value) {
        this._config = value;
    }

    blah () {

        if (this.config.blah)
            console.log(this.config.blah);
    }
}

let that = new MyClass({
    blah: 'helloWorld'
});
```

Comment: this is the guidance I was looking for, ty

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyClass(config) {
  // Define any Class methods, private or exposed.
  var blah = function () {
    if (this.config.blah) { console.log(this.config.blah); }
  }

  // Set your class properties.
  this.config = config;

  // Invoke any of the functions defined above that should be run on
  // init, using .apply(this) for logical scoping.
  blah.apply(this);

  // Expose any props or methods that you want to.
  return {
    config: config,
    blah: blah
  };
}

new MyClass({blah: 'blah'});
```